Adding on the same row 2 similar content table in vuejs
I have created a table where I have 2 labels and two color inputs that needs to be displayed on the same row but be on an equal distance or at least the first label and first input be close and then some space from the second and cannot figure it out what I'm doing wrong because it's looking like this:

And my code:
<tr>
                      <td>
                        <label class="form-control-label">
                          {{ $t('labels.header_color') }}
                        </label>

                        <v-text-field
                            v-if="isEditable"
                            v-model="form.header_color"
                            name="header_color"
                            type="color"
                            @input="form.removeError('header_color')"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <label class="form-control-label m-0">
                          {{ $t('labels.header_bg_color') }}
                        </label>

                        <v-text-field
                            v-if="isEditable"
                            v-model="form.header_bg_color"
                            name="header_bg_color"
                            type="color"
                            @input="form.removeError('header_bg_color')"
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>

Any ideas how to improve it?

First of all, the code shown doesn't appear to be just plain HTML. So please at least tag / mention what framework this is using; better yet, provide a proper [mre] of your issue, using the actually resulting HTML.

Do you really have no table tag around the tr's? Use your browser developer tools and in case this is Vue, remember Vue developer tools exist, they can also help debug. Otherwise only post the resulting HTML and CSS (use the <> button!).
